# How do I get the node count of SKSpriteNodes not visible in the scene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

If you have:

```
skView.showsNodeCount = true
```

in your GameViewController, then you can see the node count of nodes that are visible on the scene, but as soon as a node moves off the scene, this counter no longer counts it. Is there a way to see how many nodes are in your scene that are visible and not visible? This is in Xcode 6 using SpriteKit coded in Swift.

Thanks,

-Callum-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `showsNodeCount` only shows the on-screen nodes, you'd have to create your own `SKSpriteNode` class and create a method like `addMyChild`. And whenever you call the `addMyChild` method you increase a counter by one so that you manually know, how many nodes exist. for example:

```
func addMyChild(node:SKSpriteNode){
    self.addChild(node)
    nodeCount++
}
```

Comment: This is somewhat useful, but the whole purpose was to make sure there were not any accidental build up of nodes off the screen. I suppose I can just count them like this, and then subtract from this when I delete a node. It won't be perfect, but I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: Just tried it out and found a build up of about 50 nodes after a minute of running that I forgot to delete off screen. Works great, thanks again.